# CUDA+HD4600 Graphics on Optimus notebook

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I use Debian 8 and I think that I have an Optimus notebook (ASUS UX501JW CN-245T). According to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/is-a-nvidia-geforce-with-optimus-technology-supported-by-ubuntu) this architecture is not supported well on linux. I have the following goals:

- CUDA should work. I have installed the official toolkit from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). This automatically installed the proprietary nvidia graphics driver on my system. Now I can run the sample CUDA programs, but for some reason I do not have graphics acceleration enabled on my system.
- I do not need graphics acceleration because I only use awesome window manager and it works fine.
- I want to fix this error: In Android Studio, I get the following error[image]

My questions:

1. Does the error message mean that I need to have graphics acceleration?
2. If yes, can I use the Intel HD4600 somehow for this (because of the Optimus problems)?
3. What do I have to do to fix this?

Content of /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[     4.254] 
X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Release Date: 2014-12-20
[     4.254] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     4.254] Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[     4.254] Current Operating System: Linux UX501JW 4.5.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.5.3-2~bpo8+1 (2016-05-13) x86_64
[     4.254] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.5.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 root=UUID=a961c687-249d-4e1b-817b-44dca827bb0e ro quiet rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1
[     4.254] Build Date: 11 February 2015  12:32:02AM
[     4.254] xorg-server 2:1.16.4-1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[     4.254] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[     4.254]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     4.254] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     4.254] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan 28 17:27:17 2017
[     4.257] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[     4.257] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     4.267] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[     4.267] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[     4.267] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[     4.269] (**) |   |-->Device "Card1"
[     4.269] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[     4.269] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[     4.269] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     4.269] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     4.269] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     4.273] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     4.273]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.287] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     4.287]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.287] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[     4.287] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     4.287] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[     4.287] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[     4.287] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[     4.288] (II) Loader magic: 0x55be93fb2d80
[     4.288] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     4.288]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     4.288]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[     4.288]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[     4.288]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[     4.288] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     4.289] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:1043:18dd rev 6, Mem @ 0xec400000/4194304, 0x80000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[     4.289] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:139b:1043:18dd rev 162, Mem @ 0xeb000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[     4.291] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[     4.291] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     4.300] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     4.390] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     4.390]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.390]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     4.391] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  361.42  Tue Mar 22 17:25:45 PDT 2016
[     4.392] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[     4.392] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[     4.396] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.396]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 2.21.15
[     4.396]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     4.396]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[     4.396] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, HD Graphics,
    HD Graphics 2000, HD Graphics 3000, HD Graphics 2500,
    HD Graphics 4000, HD Graphics P4000, HD Graphics 4600,
    HD Graphics 5000, HD Graphics P4600/P4700, Iris(TM) Graphics 5100,
    HD Graphics 4400, HD Graphics 4200, Iris(TM) Pro Graphics 5200
[     4.397] (++) using VT number 7

[     4.403] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     4.403] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[     4.403] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     4.403] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
[     4.403] (**) intel(0): Relaxed fencing enabled
[     4.403] (**) intel(0): Wait on SwapBuffers? enabled
[     4.403] (**) intel(0): Triple buffering? enabled
[     4.403] (**) intel(0): Framebuffer tiled
[     4.403] (**) intel(0): Pixmaps tiled
[     4.403] (**) intel(0): 3D buffers tiled
[     4.403] (**) intel(0): SwapBuffers wait enabled
[     4.403] (==) intel(0): video overlay key set to 0x101fe
[     4.405] (II) intel(0): Output eDP1 using monitor section Monitor0
[     4.405] (--) intel(0): found backlight control interface /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
[     4.405] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
[     4.660] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[     4.916] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI2 has no monitor section
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): EDID for output eDP1
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Manufacturer: SDC  Model: 324c  Serial#: 0
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Year: 2013  Week: 0
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): EDID Version: 1.4
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Digital Display Input
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): 6 bits per channel
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Digital interface is DisplayPort
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 34  vert.: 19
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Gamma: 2.20
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): No DPMS capabilities specified
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Preferred mode is native pixel format and refresh rate
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): redX: 0.620 redY: 0.355   greenX: 0.300 greenY: 0.580
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): blueX: 0.150 blueY: 0.090   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Supported detailed timing:
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): clock: 143.0 MHz   Image Size:  344 x 194 mm
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 1968  h_sync_end 2000 h_blank_end 2080 h_border: 0
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1082  v_sync_end 1087 v_blanking: 1144 v_border: 0
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Unknown vendor-specific block f
[     4.917] (II) intel(0):  SAMSUNG
[     4.917] (II) intel(0):  156HL01-102
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): EDID (in hex):
[     4.917] (II) intel(0):     00ffffffffffff004c834c3200000000
[     4.917] (II) intel(0):     00170104952213780ace859e5b4c9426
[     4.917] (II) intel(0):     17505400000001010101010101010101
[     4.917] (II) intel(0):     010101010101dc3780a0703840403020
[     4.917] (II) intel(0):     250058c2100000190000000f00000000
[     4.917] (II) intel(0):     00000000001e82105200000000fe0053
[     4.917] (II) intel(0):     414d53554e470a2020202020000000fe
[     4.917] (II) intel(0):     00313536484c30312d3130320a2000d1
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "320x240" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "400x300" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "400x300" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "512x384" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "640x480" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "640x512" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "800x600" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "896x672" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "928x696" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "960x720" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "576x432" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "680x384" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "680x384" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "700x525" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "720x450" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "800x512" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "840x525" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "840x525" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "960x540" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "960x600" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Not using default mode "1024x768" (doublescan mode not supported)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Printing probed modes for output eDP1
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.1  143.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1082 1087 1144 -hsync -vsync (68.8 kHz eP)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x59.9  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x60.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x59.9  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x1024"x60.2  103.12  1600 1600 1656 1664  1024 1024 1029 1030 +hsync +vsync (62.0 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x60.0  122.00  1400 1488 1640 1880  1050 1052 1064 1082 +hsync +vsync (64.9 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1360x768"x59.8   84.75  1360 1432 1568 1776  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1360x768"x60.0   72.00  1360 1408 1440 1520  768 771 781 790 +hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1152x864"x60.0   81.62  1152 1216 1336 1520  864 865 868 895 -hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz d)
[     4.917] (II) intel(0): EDID for output DP1
[     5.172] (II) intel(0): EDID for output HDMI1
[     5.432] (II) intel(0): EDID for output HDMI2
[     5.432] (II) intel(0): Output eDP1 connected
[     5.432] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 disconnected
[     5.432] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 disconnected
[     5.432] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI2 disconnected
[     5.432] (II) intel(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[     5.432] (II) intel(0): Output eDP1 using initial mode 1920x1080
[     5.432] (II) intel(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[     5.432] (II) intel(0): Kernel page flipping support detected, enabling
[     5.432] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[     5.432] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     5.432] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     5.432] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     5.435] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.435]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.435]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     5.435] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[     5.435] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     5.435] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[     5.435] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[     5.436] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[     5.436] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[     5.436] (II) intel(0): Allocated new frame buffer 1920x1080 stride 7680, tiled
[     5.438] (II) UXA(0): Driver registered support for the following operations:
[     5.438] (II)         solid
[     5.438] (II)         copy
[     5.438] (II)         composite (RENDER acceleration)
[     5.438] (II)         put_image
[     5.438] (II)         get_image
[     5.438] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[     5.438] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[     5.438] (II) intel(0): Initializing HW Cursor
[     5.438] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[     5.439] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[     5.439] (==) intel(0): Intel XvMC decoder enabled
[     5.439] (II) intel(0): Set up textured video
[     5.439] (II) intel(0): [XvMC] xvmc_vld driver initialized.
[     5.439] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 Enabled
[     5.439] (==) intel(0): hotplug detection: "enabled"
[     5.460] (--) RandR disabled
[     5.464] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[     5.465] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
[     5.465] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 508 x 285
[     5.506] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[     5.506] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.506] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[     5.506] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[     5.509] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.509]    compiled for 1.16.0, module version = 2.9.0
[     5.509]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     5.509]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[     5.509] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[     5.509] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[     5.509] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[     5.509] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[     5.509] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[     5.509] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.509] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input7/event3"
[     5.509] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[     5.509] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.509] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.509] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     5.510] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Asus Wireless Radio Control (/dev/input/event4)
[     5.510] (**) Asus Wireless Radio Control: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.510] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Asus Wireless Radio Control'
[     5.510] (**) Asus Wireless Radio Control: always reports core events
[     5.510] (**) evdev: Asus Wireless Radio Control: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[     5.510] (--) evdev: Asus Wireless Radio Control: Vendor 0x1043 Product 0
[     5.510] (--) evdev: Asus Wireless Radio Control: Found keys
[     5.510] (II) evdev: Asus Wireless Radio Control: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.510] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ATK4002:00/input/input8/event4"
[     5.510] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Asus Wireless Radio Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[     5.510] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.510] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.510] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     5.510] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event9)
[     5.510] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.510] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[     5.510] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[     5.510] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event9"
[     5.510] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[     5.510] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[     5.510] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.510] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input17/event9"
[     5.510] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[     5.510] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.510] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.510] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     5.510] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event8)
[     5.510] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.510] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[     5.510] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[     5.510] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event8"
[     5.510] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[     5.510] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[     5.510] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.510] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:50/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input16/event8"
[     5.510] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[     5.510] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.511] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.511] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     5.511] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event1)
[     5.511] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.511] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.511] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event2)
[     5.511] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.511] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Sleep Button'
[     5.511] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[     5.511] (**) evdev: Sleep Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[     5.511] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x3
[     5.511] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Found keys
[     5.511] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.511] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input6/event2"
[     5.511] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[     5.511] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.511] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.511] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     5.511] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event11)
[     5.511] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.511] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.512] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event12)
[     5.512] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.512] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.512] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event13)
[     5.512] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.512] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.512] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam (/dev/input/event7)
[     5.512] (**) USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.512] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam'
[     5.512] (**) USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: always reports core events
[     5.512] (**) evdev: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: Device: "/dev/input/event7"
[     5.512] (--) evdev: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: Vendor 0x4f2 Product 0xb3fd
[     5.512] (--) evdev: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: Found keys
[     5.512] (II) evdev: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.512] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/input/input15/event7"
[     5.512] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[     5.512] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.512] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.512] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     5.512] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event10)
[     5.512] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.512] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.512] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Asus WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event6)
[     5.512] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.512] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Asus WMI hotkeys'
[     5.512] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[     5.512] (**) evdev: Asus WMI hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[     5.513] (--) evdev: Asus WMI hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[     5.513] (--) evdev: Asus WMI hotkeys: Found keys
[     5.513] (II) evdev: Asus WMI hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.513] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input14/event6"
[     5.513] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Asus WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[     5.513] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.513] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.513] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     5.513] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[     5.513] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     5.513] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[     5.513] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[     5.513] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[     5.513] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[     5.513] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[     5.513] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[     5.513] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0/event0"
[     5.513] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[     5.513] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.513] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.513] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     5.513] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/event14)
[     5.513] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[     5.513] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[     5.513] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[     5.513] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[     5.513] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[     5.513] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[     5.514] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.514]    compiled for 1.16.0.901, module version = 1.8.99
[     5.514]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     5.514]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[     5.514] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
[     5.514] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[     5.514] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event14"
[     5.548] (II) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: found clickpad property
[     5.548] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 3097 (res 31)
[     5.548] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 2119 (res 32)
[     5.548] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: pressure range 0 - 255
[     5.548] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: finger width range 0 - 15
[     5.548] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: buttons: left double triple
[     5.548] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0xe
[     5.548] (**) Option "AreaRightEdge" "3000"
[     5.548] (**) Option "VertScrollDelta" "100"
[     5.548] (**) Option "HorizScrollDelta" "60"
[     5.548] (**) Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
[     5.548] (**) Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
[     5.548] (**) Option "TapButton1" "1"
[     5.548] (**) Option "TapButton2" "3"
[     5.548] (**) Option "TapButton3" "2"
[     5.548] (**) Option "PalmDetect" "1"
[     5.548] (**) Option "PalmMinWidth" "3"
[     5.548] (**) Option "PalmMinZ" "63"
[     5.548] (**) Option "SingleTapTimeout" "150"
[     5.548] (**) Option "MinSpeed" "0.5"
[     5.548] (**) Option "MaxSpeed" "1"
[     5.548] (**) Option "AccelFactor" "0.067"
[     5.548] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[     5.548] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[     5.548] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[     5.588] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio4/input/input13/event14"
[     5.588] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 14)
[     5.588] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.0
[     5.588] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 2.00
[     5.588] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.067
[     5.588] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     5.588] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[     5.588] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     5.588] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     5.588] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[     5.588] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[     5.588] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[     5.588] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event5)
[     5.588] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.588] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Output of `glxinfo` (shortened, the second line is repeated very often):

```
name of display: :0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```